# PYPY3 -- Unable to install Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have been trying to install pandas in PYPY with out any success. Below is the complete log message.

**Windows 10 64 Bit OS**.

Have installed the Visual C++ 2015-2019 redistributable.

**Python 3.7** , **pip 19.3.1** ( installed through Anaconda)

**pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32**

how to resolve this error?

Collecting pandas
  Using cached

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/93/b544dd08092b457d88e10fc1e0989d9397fd32ca936fdfcbb2584178dd2b/pandas-0.25.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable DF
    Could not locate executable efl
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py:419: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
    C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_egg.py", line 163, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 26, in run
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 142, in run
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 153, in build_sources
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 286, in build_library_sources
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 369, in generate_sources
  File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 667, in get_mathlib_info
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\command\config.py", line 243, in try_link
    self._check_compiler()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\command\config.py", line 54, in _check_compiler
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 50, in initialize
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 385, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 147, in msvc9_query_vcvarsall
    return EnvironmentInfo(arch, ver).return_env()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 1227, in return_env
    [self.VCIncludes,
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 876, in VCIncludes
    return [os.path.join(self.si.VCInstallDir, 'Include'),
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 555, in VCInstallDir
    raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(msg)
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 444, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 436, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 444, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\setup.py", line 436, in setup_package
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2kmbrdot\numpy-1.17.4\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 171, in setup
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\core.py", line 163, in setup
    raise SystemExit("error: " + str(msg))
SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-e7lqmamq\pandas\setup.py", line 840, in <module>
    **setuptools_kwargs
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 142, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 137, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 586, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1063, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1075, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 653, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "C:\Users\Nawab\Desktop\pypy3.6-v7.2.0-win32\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1146, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this solved. numpy is not supported PYPY3 yet, installed pypy then numpy and pandas, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error in the past by using visual studio and installed only the visual c++ redistribution.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads

I hope this may help.

Comment: did not work even after installation , it still gives me the same message.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to update setuptools by

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Also, you can see that log suggest you download MCV C++

> SystemExit: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Thank you for the replies.

Even after the tools upgrade and installing the C++ package from visual studio still getting the same error