# how to install pandas in pypy3?

Tags: python, pandas, pypy

I have a following problem. I have installed pypy3 on my Ubuntu. I would like to install pandas package. I do it using `pypy3 -m pip install pandas`. But I got following error:

```
WARNING: Value for scheme.platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/../../local/lib/pypy3.6/dist-packages
sysconfig: /usr/lib/pypy3/site-packages
WARNING: Value for scheme.purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/../../local/lib/pypy3.6/dist-packages
sysconfig: /usr/lib/pypy3/site-packages
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/../../local/include
sysconfig: /usr/lib/pypy3/include/UNKNOWN
WARNING: Value for scheme.scripts does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/../../local/bin
sysconfig: /usr/lib/pypy3/bin
WARNING: Value for scheme.data does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/../../local
sysconfig: /usr/lib/pypy3
WARNING: Additional context:
user = False
home = None
root = None
prefix = None
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.1.5.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  WARNING: Value for prefixed-purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/normal/site-packages
  sysconfig: /tmp/local/lib/pypy3.6/lib-python
  WARNING: Value for prefixed-platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/normal/site-packages
  sysconfig: /tmp/local/lib/pypy3.6/lib-python
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = '/tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/normal'
  WARNING: Value for prefixed-purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay/site-packages
  sysconfig: /tmp/local/lib/pypy3.6/lib-python
  WARNING: Value for prefixed-platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay/site-packages
  sysconfig: /tmp/local/lib/pypy3.6/lib-python
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = '/tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay'
  WARNING: Value for purelib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/dist-packages
  sysconfig: /usr/local/lib/pypy3.6/lib-python
  WARNING: Additional context:
  user = False
  home = None
  root = None
  prefix = None
  WARNING: Value for platlib does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10151>
  distutils: /usr/lib/pypy3/dist-packages
  sysconfig: /usr/local/lib/pypy3.6/lib-python
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/pypy3 /home/vojtam/.local/lib/pypy3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (774 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-58.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (946 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.37.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
  Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.21
    Using cached Cython-0.29.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (979 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.15.4
    Using cached numpy-1.15.4.zip (4.5 MB)
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
    Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
    Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-91_otg2f
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/
    Complete output (364 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    blis_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    openblas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    atlas_blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE
  
  
  
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, numpy, Cython
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/bin/pypy3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0ftvn40b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay/include/numpy
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/
      Complete output (358 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
  
      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
  
        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
  
  
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      blis_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
          Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
          the ATLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
      non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
      /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
      F2PY Version 2
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      lapack_info:
      customize UnixCCompiler
        libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      /tmp/pip-install-gpher0s_/numpy_9f2456ae65fe40749181bd0050e0570b/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:625: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE
 
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/e4/828bb9c2474ff6016e5ce96a78220d485436d5468c23068f4f6c2eb9cff8/pandas-1.1.5.tar.gz#sha256=f10fc41ee3c75a474d3bdf68d396f10782d013d7f67db99c0efbfd0acb99701b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/) (requires-python:>=3.6.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/pypy3 /home/vojtam/.local/lib/pypy3.6/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-8dqfm6qw/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.15.4; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried to follow the advice here ([PYPY3 -- Unable to install Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177892/pypy3-unable-to-install-pandas)) and i tried to install numpy first, but it did not help.

My pypy3 contains following packages (I run `pypy3 -m pip list`):

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- --------------------
alabaster                    0.7.8
apturl                       0.5.2
astroid                      2.3.3
attrs                        19.3.0
Babel                        2.6.0
backcall                     0.1.0
bleach                       3.1.1
blinker                      1.4
catfish                      1.4.13
certifi                      2019.11.28
cffi                         1.14.0
chardet                      3.0.4
Click                        7.0
cloudpickle                  1.3.0
colorama                     0.4.3
command-not-found            0.3
cryptography                 2.8
cupshelpers                  1.0
dbus-python                  1.2.16
decorator                    4.4.2
defer                        1.0.6
defusedxml                   0.6.0
distro                       1.4.0
distro-info                  0.23ubuntu1
docutils                     0.16
entrypoints                  0.3
greenlet                     0.4.13
html5lib                     1.0.1
httplib2                     0.14.0
idna                         2.8
imagesize                    1.2.0
importlib-metadata           1.5.0
ipykernel                    5.2.0
ipython                      7.13.0
ipython_genutils             0.2.0
isort                        4.3.4
jedi                         0.15.2
Jinja2                       2.10.1
jsonschema                   3.2.0
jupyter-client               6.1.2
jupyter-core                 4.6.3
keyring                      18.0.1
language-selector            0.1
launchpadlib                 1.10.13
lazr.restfulclient           0.14.2
lazr.uri                     1.0.3
lazy-object-proxy            1.4.3
lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings 1.2.2
logilab-common               1.4.3
MarkupSafe                   1.1.0
mccabe                       0.6.1
menulibre                    2.2.1
mistune                      0.8.4
mock                         3.0.5
more-itertools               4.2.0
mugshot                      0.4.2
nbconvert                    5.6.1
nbformat                     5.0.4
netifaces                    0.10.4
numpy                        1.19.5
numpydoc                     0.7.0
oauthlib                     3.1.0
olefile                      0.46
onboard                      1.4.1
packaging                    20.3
pandocfilters                1.4.2
parso                        0.5.2
pbr                          5.4.5
pexpect                      4.6.0
pickleshare                  0.7.5
Pillow                       7.0.0
pip                          21.3.1
prompt-toolkit               2.0.10
psutil                       5.5.1
pycairo                      1.16.2
pycodestyle                  2.5.0
pycups                       1.9.73
pyflakes                     2.1.1
Pygments                     2.3.1
PyGObject                    3.36.0
PyJWT                        1.7.1
pylint                       2.4.4
pymacaroons                  0.13.0
PyNaCl                       1.3.0
pyparsing                    2.4.6
PyQt5                        5.14.1
pyrsistent                   0.15.5
pysvn                        1.9.9
python-apt                   2.0.0+ubuntu0.20.4.6
python-dateutil              2.7.3
python-debian                0.1.36ubuntu1
pytz                         2019.3
PyYAML                       5.3.1
pyzmq                        18.1.1
QtAwesome                    0.4.4
qtconsole                    4.6.0
QtPy                         1.9.0
readline                     6.2.4.1
reportlab                    3.5.34
requests                     2.22.0
requests-unixsocket          0.2.0
roman                        2.0.0
rope                         0.10.5
SecretStorage                2.3.1
setuptools                   45.2.0
sgt-launcher                 0.2.5
simplejson                   3.16.0
sip                          4.19.21
six                          1.14.0
Sphinx                       1.8.5
spyder                       3.3.6
spyder-kernels               0.5.2
systemd-python               234
testpath                     0.4.4
tornado                      5.1.1
traitlets                    4.3.3
ubuntu-advantage-tools       27.2
ubuntu-drivers-common        0.0.0
ufw                          0.36
unattended-upgrades          0.1
urllib3                      1.25.8
vboxapi                      1.0
wadllib                      1.3.3
wcwidth                      0.1.8
webencodings                 0.5.1
wheel                        0.34.2
wrapt                        1.11.2
xcffib                       0.8.1
xkit                         0.0.0
zipp                         1.0.0
```

How can I install pandas in PyPy3 please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install pandas on pypy3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64682472/unable-to-install-pandas-on-pypy3-6)

Comment: @Latra No, because I don`t use Conda

Comment: error shows `UnixCCompiler` so it tries to compile some C/C++ code but for many C/C++ libraries it displays `NOT AVAILABLE` - it can means you have to first install source code of these C/C++ libraries - and/or modules with suffix `-dev` which should have files `.h` with headers needed to compile other modules. Maybe you find them with `apt search ...` and install with `apt install ...`

Answer (score 1):

Install C++ Compiler. It should work then

```
sudo apt install g++
```